# combine join and union from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are one example table called `pages`

```
id  page_name    page_alias   lang
1   pagina1        pagina1     es
2   pagina2        pagina2     es
3   page1          pagina1     en
4   page2          pagina2     en
```

I know the `page_name` = `pagina1`, the source `lang` = `es` and destination `lang` = `en`

So based in the page_name and source lang I need to get this entry and one other entry with the destination lang where the alias is the same as the first result

I have tried this but not work (only get the first entry)

```
SELECT A.* FROM pages AS A
JOIN pages AS B
ON
B.page_alias = A.page_alias AND B.lang = 'en'   
WHERE A.page_name = 'pagina1' AND A.lang = 'es'
```

Expected query result (two rows):

```
1   pagina1        pagina1     es
3   page1          pagina1     en
```

It semm need a UNION but I dont know how to use the page_alias from the first query into a UNION query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
select *
from pages
where page_alias in (
    select page_alias
    from pages
    where page_name = 'pagina1' and lang = 'es'
    )
and lang in ('en', 'es')
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/811413/1)

Comment: That seem to be nearby to my needs but get all entryes ( if have other languages with the same `page_alias `) I need only the `es` lang and `en` lang .... see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c82d84/1

Comment: You can always add an additional filter in the `where` clause, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use UNION if the column you search for is either ES on EN.  Use IN clause instead.

here is a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15afd1/8

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM pages AS A
JOIN pages AS B
ON B.page_alias = A.page_alias 
 AND B.page_name = 'pagina1'
WHERE A.lang in ('es', 'en')
```

Comment: Yes you have reason that work based in my tiny example table but I don't know why in my real project return six rows as result (3 times 2 rows) klin

Comment: So the result is correct ... id name lang es en  but show it repeated 3 times the same ... and with klin answer above ... work as espected ... I can't post the real data ... I have aprox 5000 pages in 46 languges

Comment: So you have duplicated data with different ID? show me the duplicated data aside from what you posted. thanks.

Comment: No. the Id is the same ( and is unique primary key) ... for example I got id 1 and 3 ... three times as result (not duplicate id-s)

Comment: Only one thing. ... The `page_name` can be the same in other language ... I thing is for that

Comment: probably bug on sqlfiddle. I put distinct to fix it.

Comment: the where clause will filter it. In case other language other than ES has the same page_name='pahina1'

Comment: Yes. With `DISTINCT` it work. But I like to be fairplay ...  I get you only a upvote (klin answer has been first) Thank you for your help